# Jeffreys prior for binomial likelihood

Tags: bayesian, jeffreys-prior

If I use a Jeffreys prior for a binomial probability parameter $\theta$ then this implies using a $\theta \sim beta(1/2,1/2)$ distribution.

If I transform to a new frame of reference $\phi = \theta^2$ then clearly $\phi$ is not also distributed as a $beta(1/2,1/2)$ distribution.

My question is in what sense is Jeffreys prior invariant to reparameterisations? I think I am misunderstanding the topic to be honest ...

Comment: Jeffreys' prior is invariant in the sense that starting with a Jeffreys prior for one parameterisation and running the appropriate change of variable is identical to deriving the Jeffreys prior directly for this new parameterisation. Actually, _equivariant_ would be more appropriate a term than _invariant_.

Comment: @ben18785: take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38962/why-is-the-jeffreys-prior-useful

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210607/in-what-sense-is-the-jeffreys-prior-invariant (more or less the same question I think, but on a different site).

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139001/example-for-a-prior-that-unlike-jeffreys-leads-to-a-posterior-that-is-not-inva

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lets have $\phi = g(\theta)$, where $g$ is a monotone function of $\theta$ and let $h$ be the inverse of $g$, so that $\theta = h(\phi)$. We can obtain Jeffrey's prior distribution $p_{J}(\phi)$ in two ways:

1. Start with the Binomial model (1)
   \begin{equation} \label{original}
   p(y | \theta) = \binom{n}{y} \theta^{y} (1-\theta)^{n-y}
   \end{equation}
   reparameterize the model with $\phi = g(\theta)$ to get
   $$
   p(y | \phi) = \binom{n}{y} h(\phi)^{y} (1-h(\phi))^{n-y}
   $$
   and obtain Jeffrey's prior distribution $p_{J}(\phi)$ for this model.
2. Obtain Jeffrey's prior distribution $p_{J}(\theta)$ from original Binomial model 1 and apply the change of variables formula to obtain the induced prior density on $\phi$
   $$
   p_{J}(\phi) = p_{J}(h(\phi)) |\frac{dh}{d\phi}|.
   $$

To be invariant to reparameterisations means that densities $p_{J}(\phi)$ derived in both ways should be the same. Jeffrey's prior has this characteristic [Reference: [A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods by P. Hoff](http://www.stat.washington.edu/people/pdhoff/book.php).]

To answer your comment. To obtain Jeffrey's prior distribution $p_{J}(\theta)$ from the likelihood for Binomial model
$$
p(y | \theta) = \binom{n}{y} \theta^{y} (1-\theta)^{n-y}
$$ 
we must calculate Fisher information by taking logarithm of likelihood $l$ and calculate second derivative of $l$
\begin{align*}
l := \log(p(y | \theta)) &\propto y \log(\theta) + (n-y) \log(1-\theta) \\
\frac{\partial l }{\partial \theta} &= \frac{y}{\theta} - \frac{n-y}{1-\theta} \\
\frac{\partial^{2} l }{\partial \theta^{2}} &= -\frac{y}{\theta^{2}} - \frac{n-y}{ (1-\theta)^{2} }
\end{align*}
and Fisher information is
\begin{align*}
I(\theta) &= -E(\frac{\partial^{2} l }{\partial \theta^{2}} | \theta) \\
&= \frac{n\theta}{\theta^{2}} + \frac{n - n \theta}{(1-\theta)^{2}} \\
&= \frac{n}{\theta ( 1- \theta)} \\
&\propto \theta^{-1} (1-\theta)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Jeffrey's prior for this model is
\begin{align*}
p_{J}(\theta) &=  \sqrt{I(\theta)} \\
&\propto \theta^{-1/2} (1-\theta)^{-1/2}
\end{align*}
which is $\texttt{beta}(1/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Afraid I am being a bit slow though. In what sense can we obtain a prior from a likelihood? They are two separate things, and the latter does not imply the former...

Comment: I answered above by obtaining a Jeffrey's prior $p_{J}(\theta)$ from the likelihood for Binomial model.