# What is the point of using a Bayesian prior?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, sampling, prior, frequentist

I do struggle with the most basic starting point of Bayesian statistics: **why is using a prior useful**?

It seems to me that if anything they hurt much more than help.
Moreover, Bayesians always say things like "the more evidence you get the less important a prior becomes". So why use them in the first place?

Especially if you have start with a prior that is really **far-off**, then you will be hurting your estimates.

To me a "Frequentist" approach seems much simpler and more straightforward.

I would like to discuss here an example that is very typical in introductory Bayesian course/explanations (e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFDbGp5YzjqXQ4oE4w9GVWdiokWB9gEpm), [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/bayesian-inference-intuition-and-example-148fd8fb95d6), [or this](https://willhipson.netlify.app/post/bayesian_intro/binomial_gold/))

#### Example 1 -- Are French people Rude?

[image]

Imagine that I am interested in estimating if French people are rude (in a binary way: Rude vs Non-Rude).

Imagine that the true parameter $\theta$ is 0.3, 30% of French are rude.

I have a random sample of 100 people with data on "rudeness".

A straightforward "Frequentist" approach would be: compute your confidence intervals on the sample and ... you done. We know what is the probability that the true $\theta$ lies within our CI, and we know that our sample average, on average, thanks to the Central Limit Theorem, will be close to the true parameter.

```r
    true_theta = 0.3
    set.seed(111)

    # population
    X = rbinom(n = 10000, size = 1, prob = true_theta)

    # sample of 100
    x = sample(X, size = 100)
    p_hat = prop.table(table(x))[2]
    margin_error = 1.96 * sqrt( (p_hat*(1-p_hat)) / 100  
    ci_low = p_hat - margin_error
    ci_high = p_hat + margin_error
    data.frame(p_hat, ci_low, ci_high)
```

Now Bayesian will try to incorporate priors into this. Why?

We can imagine that most people will have beliefs that French are rude. (Using a Beta distribution) based on personal experience, someone would typically have a prior distribution like this: they know 10 French people and 7 are rude. So that is their prior.

The results are shown in the Figure above. On the bottom panel, I draw the Confidence Intervals around the sample mean.

It seems to me that the Frequentist approach will gives us a more **precise and immediate** answer to this question.

What am I missing here?

### Example 2 -- Forecast Knock Out

Imagine I am interested in forecasting Knocked out (KO) in the Ultimate Fighting Championship (UFC).

My basic Frequentist approach would go like this.

Study the sport and see what variables play a role in predicting a fighter knocking another fighter (e.g. age of the fighters, winning streak, home advantage, …).

Then I will sample 30 UFC events and start build my model. I would use a simple logistic regression with maximum likelihood.
I don’t have prior per see, but I have a model of reality that I built on theoretical knowledge, like any scientists do, Bayesian or not.
My initial model would be that age and style of fighting (Muay Thai fighter vs BJJ) would be the most important factors predicting a KO.

I retrieve estimates from my logistic regression. Then I would cross-validate, take another sample and apply my initial model to the new data and see how it perform.

Let’s imagine that it doesn’t perform too well. I will then try to improve my model in studying more closely the sport. I find that accounting for an interaction between injury and age of the fighter is one of the most important predictors a KO. I re-run my regression with this and again cross validate, and now the model perform well.

Now I have a forecasting model telling me the probability of a KO and I can use it to bet money.

Furthermore, I know that certain special events, like a New Year's Eve event, will have more KOs, so I can adjust my model according to that fact.

Where would a prior, in the Bayesian sense, be useful here? Frequentists like all scientists use model to test reality and improve their models over time, but the difference is that they don’t put a formal initial probability on things. I still do not see why, you would want to do that.

```r
    # code for the Figure
    theta_range <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
    prior <- dbeta(x = theta_range, shape1 = 7, shape2 = 3)

    # observed success
    success_obs = table(x)[2]
    failure_obs = table(x)[1]

    # sampling distribution #
    likelihood <- dbinom(x = success_obs, size = 100, 
                           prob = theta_range) * 100

    # posterior 
    posterior_density <- likelihood * prior

   df <- data.frame(theta = theta_range,
                     likelihood = likelihood,
                     prior_dist = prior,
                     posterior_distribution = posterior_density)

    df_melt = melt(df, id.vars = 'theta')

    df_melt %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = theta, y = value, color = variable)) + 
      geom_line(size = 1.2) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = p_hat, size = 1.5) + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = ci_low, colour = 'gray', 
                                      size = 1.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = ci_high, colour = 'gray', 
                             size = 1.5) + theme_minimal() +
      ggtitle("Bayesian + Frequentist Confidence Intervals")
```

Comment: At a high level, a prior is used to incorporate domain knowledge into a problem. To see why domain knowledge is important, see [this wonderful answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222189/296197).

Comment: If you Have a prior then why not use it? Sometimes you do have it genuinely.

Comment: The Bayesian approach can be very natural in sequential/online settings where you have a stream of incoming data. While the initial prior is arbitrary, after some time, your new prior (the previous posterior) will actually encode domain knowledge. On the other hand, if you are estimating a sample mean and have no domain knowledge then I don't really see the utility of using a Bayesian flat-prior approach (unless you plan to use your posterior as a prior in a down stream task).

Comment: What I struggle with is that Bayesians makes it like Frequentists dont have models and just conduct research blindly, but this is far from reality. When you build models (simple OLS regression or complicated Path analyses) you do incorporate knowledge and you can always use all sorts of corrections after seeing new data. It seems artificial to me this idea that only Bayesian use informed modeling. But in many cases when your prior is really off, you are better off getting rid of it. What's the point of multiplying the likelihood by the prior if you see that the data contradict your prior.

Comment: In my opinion some Bayesians overstate their case and you are right to be skeptical. This however doesn't mean that the Bayesian approach is useless. Surely it is useful if the prior encodes reliable and helpful information (in which case it isn't "off", unless something very strange has happened). This is not the case in your examples.

Comment: Note also that Bayesians tend to use informationless priors or at least priors that give the parameters lots of space in case there is no reliable and precise prior information. Also in this case the prior will not normally be "off" (how much it helps then is another matter).

Comment: In answer to the question "What's the point of multiplying the likelihood by the prior if you see that the data contradict your prior" - it helps you avoid mistakes such as believing that [Paul the octopus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Octopus) could predict football match results. The data contradicted the prior that Paul was very unlikely to be psychic, but the prior was obviously right.

Comment: @fblundun sorry what the prior about Paul el polpo?

Comment: @Lewian thanks for your answer. I dont think Bayesian is useless, I am just trying to understand where it makes most sense. Bayesian are really selling you the moon, but their most basic arguments for Bayesian do not really kick asses, like stuff like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r76oDIvwETI&list=PLFDbGp5YzjqXQ4oE4w9GVWdiokWB9gEpm&index=2

Comment: like as if a Frequentist doctor would be much worse than a Bayesian!

Comment: There are some settings where using a prior results in estimators which are too good to be true. For the normal location model, there exists priors for which the corresponding Bayes estimators are minimax and (of course) admissible. How can you argue against an admissible estimator which always beats the frequentist MLE?

Comment: @giac hopefully your prior about Paul is that he is very unlikely to be able to psychically predict football results!

Comment: @user257566 can you send me a paper or reference on that?

Comment: @fblundun don't tell me that about Paul! I need to believe that he has real psychic power.

Comment: @giac what is your view on ridge regression?

Comment: @giac "A straightforward "Frequentist" approach would be: compute your confidence intervals on the sample and ... you done. We know what is the probability that the true θ lies within our CI,"  I don't think a frequentist can attach a non-trivial probability to the hypothesis that the true statistic lies in a particular interval, as it doesn't have a long run frequency, it is either in that particular interval, or it isn't.  Confidence intervals are anything but "straightforward", at least in their interpretation.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the/26457#26457

Comment: OP, you might find https://www.fharrell.com/post/journey/ writings helpful ( as an experienced  frequentist turned bayesian)

Comment: @DikranMarsupial thanks for the reference, I will dig into it

Comment: @seanv507 looks interesting thanks

Comment: @giac I've been reading a book called: "Statistical Rethinking" by Richard McElreath that has a very good explanation of priors.  As well as how they tend to have very little influence on the model when the data set size increases.

Comment: @jeffalltogether thanks for the recommendation. But then again, if you have a large sample, why even bother with priors?

Comment: @giac from the book on Pg. 34: "In Bayesian statistics you must have an initial plausibility assignment for each possible value of the parameter."  Even if this plausibility assignment is uniform for all parameter values (i.e., the prior has zero influence) that is still a prior. "The flat prior is very common, but is hardly ever the best prior. [Weakly informative or Regularizing] priors are so useful that non-Bayesian statistical procedures have adopted a mathematically equivalent approach, Penalized Regression."

Comment: my understand of penalised regression or lasso is that it is very data driven, you let the data determine the weights of the different variables. I think that it is Bayesians that makes it like there is a massive difference between how science is done between Freq. vs Bayesian.

Comment: Because you can use the knowledge you already know, from other experiments or even from basic reasoning (for example discarding impossible values).
And it's also very useful for adaptative analysis.
And because it allows you to estimate the full distribution instead of just rejecting hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

There are many excellent thoughts here.  There is a short answer to the question.  If you want to gauge relative evidence you can sometimes get away without using any outside information.  Relative evidence can be summarized by a likelihood ratio in the likelihoodist school of statistics.  For example one may use study data to compute the likelihood ratio assuming that true mean blood pressure is 120mmHg vs. the mean being 140mmHg.  Or you can quantify evidence more indirectly using p-values (evidence *against* something, only).  If you want to quantify absolute evidence there is no mathematical way to compute "absolute" probabilities without having a prior distribution.  So if you wanted to compute the probability that the true mean blood pressure is between 135mmHg and 145mmHg you would need a prior.  Likewise if you wanted to compute the probability that a medical treatment lowers mortality instead of just using a frequentist hypothesis test to compute the probability of getting data stranger than ours *if* the treatment does nothing about disease risk you would need a prior.

The most compelling stories I've seen about the Bayesian approach are Nate Silver's *The Signal and the Noise* and *Bernoulli's Fallacy* by Aubry Clayton.  More thoughts are [here](https://fharrell.com/post/journey) and [here](https://hbiostat.org/bayes).

An analogy in medical diagnostic testing is often useful.  *Sensitivity* and *specificity* are sometimes used as test characteristics.  These condition on the actual disease status so only provide relative information.  To turn them into absolute information (probability of disease) one must use Bayes' rule to factor in disease prevalence (the prior).

So the prior distribution is the mathematical cost of being able to make direct statements that are not just about *relative* evidence.

Comment: Thanks, I will dig into the books you mentioned.

Comment: I like this answer, especially the final sentence.

Answer (score 4):

### Questions

> why is using a prior useful?

How do you "not use a prior"?  Even the frequentist approach has a prior—it's just unstated, but it's there all the same.  There's always a prior, whether you like it or not.

As for which prior you should use, that's a different question, which other answers on this site go over.  See for example [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38962/why-is-the-jeffreys-prior-useful).

> Especially if you have start with a prior that is really far-off, then you will be hurting your estimates.

I know what you're trying to say here, but it doesn't really make any sense.  For your prior to not "hurt your estimates", it should reflect your data.  But that's not the goal of the prior—that's the goal of the posterior.  The prior should reflect any prior knowledge you have, and otherwise be "uninformative" (if you believe that priors can be uninformative, which I do).

### Example 1

You can verify that your frequentist approach does have a hidden prior by simply redoing your calculation after transforming the parameter $\theta$.  For example, let $\beta = e^\theta$.  The frequentist approach produces a different distribution and confidence interval.  The parametrization is  part of the unstated prior.

### Example 2

Saying that you're going to use *maximum likelihood* to make your estimate is identical to using *MAP* with a flat prior.  There is nevertheless a prior, which is dependent on the model you choose.  As before, this includes its parametrization.  You can examine your prior by evaluating estimates before updating parameters given new data.

Comment: "Even the frequentist approach has a prior—it's just unstated, but it's there all the same." Not true. Just because you can write down a frequentist method as a Bayesian method with a certain prior (which doesn't always work, at least not with proper priors) it doesn't mean that "the frequentist approach has a prior".  Probability has a different meaning in frequentism, and parameters cannot normally be random variables, so it would be inappropriate to interpret whatever mathematical equivalence exists as if there really were a meaningful Bayesian prior.

Comment: @Lewian Just as you say, "you can write down a frequentist method as a Bayesian method with a certain prior".  It doesn't matter how frequentists define probability since the whole point is to view their model through the Bayesian lens under which we agree that  they are not avoiding priors.  There is always a prior.  Finally, I disagree with your idea that "it doesn't always work"—improper priors are still priors.  You should write down an example of a frequentist model that "has no prior" to examine it more carefully.

Comment: There's all kinds of trouble with improper priors and some Bayesians (starting with de Finetti who knew a thing or two about Bayesian priors) reject them. This is however not the place to discuss that in depth. Original Bayesian philosophy requires priors to fulfill the probability axioms for good reasons, which improper priors don't.

Comment: @Lewian Improper priors are not "a problem".  Also, it doesn't make sense to say that you don't use a prior.  How can you have a posterior, or a posterior predictive?  It sounds like what you mean you say "don't use a prior" is actually use a flat prior.  This is still a prior—even if it's improper.

Comment: Obviously I'm not saying that Bayesians don't use priors or that you shouldn't. Frequentists don't use a prior even if you can claim a hundreds times that this-or-that method gives the same numbers as a Bayesian one that uses an (often improper) prior. Giving the same numbers doesn't mean it has the same meaning.

Comment: @Lewian I think I said it clearly in my last comment: "It doesn't matter how frequentists define probability since the whole point is to view their model through the Bayesian lens under which we agree that they are not avoiding priors."  Simply changing your definitions is not avoiding priors.  By that logic, you could rename *prior* to *slithy toves* and claim that you were not using a prior.  Clearly, this is nonsense.

Comment: https://errorstatistics.com/2012/04/25/3594/

Comment: @NeilG thanks for your answer but I still don't get it. It seems to me that a prior in the Bayesian sense has a specific definition, not just "any knowledge you have". See my edit to my question where I added another example. Would you consider having a model of reality a prior? If yes, then what Bayesian are trying to say is not very interesting. Thanks

Comment: @giac I've edited my answer for your questions.  Yes, a model is a prior.  You may want to consider that the flat priors that you're using might be fine in practice, but aren't justifiable.

Comment: @NeilG what do you mean by not justifiable?

Comment: @giac I mean that the flat prior is arbitrarily chosen without justification while there are better choices for the prior that have justifications.

Comment: If I want to fit an bayesian model to a small dataset...  Can I first apply that model to a large dataset and use its output as prior for the small one?
For example I want to fit a regression model to see if smoking has an effect on cancer using 30 observations. And I first apply my model to a public health service database with 1 million observations.

Comment: @skan sure, but in my opinion, that's not really a prior.  That's extra likelihood from what is essentially additional data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example of how to use Bayesian priors in a way that even "frequentists" agree is useful.

Let's say you want to estimate the know how well students at 100 different schools are doing in math, so you can identify schools that are doing particularly well or poorly. But you can only assess math knowledge through a test that not all students took. At most schools well over 100 students take the test but at some schools only a few take it due (assume nonresponse is random). Overall, the average score on test is 85% but obviously you are more interested in the average score at particular schools.

Now let's say that at school B only 5 students took the test and their average score was 50%. What are we to make of this?

A purely frequentist approach would to take the data at it's word and treat 50% as the best estimate available of the average score at that school, with some fairly large confidence intervals of course.

But that seems problematic. We know that overall the average test score across all students is an 85%. Given that we only have data from five students at this school, doesn't it seem MORE likely that the true value is actually somewhere closer to the 85% than 50%? The Bayesian approach to this problem would be to treat the overall mean as a "prior" and then update that prior with the additional data we got from the five students at this school. This is going to "shrink" our final estimate towards the mean by some amount. Since we only have five students at this school it's going to shrink it by quite a bit, since the data are weak. At a school with 150 respondents we would put more trust in the data and only shrink a little bit.

This approach is called "empirical Bayes estimation" and it's widely used in multilevel modeling, even by people who don't think of themselves as Bayesian, and more explicitly Bayesian versions of this approach (Google "Multilevel regression with post-stratification") are very common in political science when trying to get estimates of public opinion in small states

This is in fact what Fivethirtyeight.com does to predict elections in the US. To estimate the chance that a given candidate (say Trump) will win a state they look at polling at that state, but then they "shrink" the result of that polling towards a prior that they got from other data.

For example, let's say that before the 2020 campaign even starts you decide that, based on demographic trends, partisan affiliation and presidential approval numbers, Trump is only likely to get 30% of the vote in Vermont (this is our prior). Then someone does a poll of 100 people and finds that Trump is actually winning in Vermont with 51% of the vote. A frequentist would have to either put total trust in this result or ignore it completely. A Bayesian can do something more subtle: we use Bayes' rule to shrink this estimate towards our prior by some amount. In other words we don't actually believe that this poll means that Trump is actually ahead in Vermont, but we also no longer totally believe our old prior that Trump was only going to get 30%. Maybe now we think that we will win 40% of the vote. Then when we get even more new data, we update the new prior again.

Philosophical disagreements aside, this approach really works, which is why Fivethirthyeights's forecasts are so accurate:
https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/checking-our-work/

Comment: Thanks that is useful. In fact, I mentioned post-stratification in one my answers, but I don't "see" it as a prior, rather some kind of "posterior correction". Maybe in the end, you get the same results, but I would rather start with what the data are telling me and then correct if I have a really good reason to do it. For instance, in my forecasting example, I know that some fighters have a X-factor, so I can correct for this. But if that is all what Bayesian is really selling, then it is much more modest than what "Bayesian revolution" claims to be.

Comment: You are right that the "post stratification" part of MRP doesn't really have much to do with Bayesianism, and that wasn't what I'm talking about above. What makes MRP and empirical Bayes estimation so popular and successful as methods is their explicit use of priors.

Comment: is Bayesian popular in your field? From my experience in the social sciences, it is still a very niche method.

Comment: in political science and sociology it is still fairly niche, but it's growing in popularity among two very different groups: highly sophisticated mathematical stats gurus like Andrew Gelman and more "critical" scholars who think that cultural and social assumptions always influence the way we do stats and so at least we should be honest about it. Both groups agree with what others here have said: we always have some sorts of priors ('biases") when we choose a statistical model and therefore Bayesianism is a more honest approach.

Comment: I bet that describing as "more honest" can stir a lot of controversy and needs much more back up. I am curious to see if in practice Bayesian are really producing more transparent and honest science. Only the future will tell.

Comment: In @Graham Wright's school example the frequentist could assume the unknown fixed true mean math score at two or more schools are equivalent and pool observations.  He could treat school as random, but this should match the sampling scheme and would mean we are making inference on a broader population of schools.  Heterogeneity does not constitute a random variable.  It is sampling that constitutes a random variable.  Turning priors into posteriors reverses cause and effect.  The sampling frame for both the data and the parameters changes, and the fix is unfalsifiable probability as belief.

Comment: @giac someone recently asked Andrew Gelman (Bayesian advocate #1) something like your initial question: how do we know a particular method (e.g. Bayesian inference) actually works better than the alternative? So this is something he thinks about a lot. https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2021/08/12/how-to-convince-yourself-that-multilevel-modeling-or-more-generally-any-advanced-statistical-method-has-benefits/

Answer (score 0):

So an important area of work that I am involved in is decision making under uncertainty, particularly where money is placed at risk.  You are asking the wrong question.

The first question should be when and where should I use a Bayesian method and when should I not, maybe never, use a Bayesian method.  The subsidiary question would be about why you care about the answer.  An academic and a person solving an applied problem, even if the question is identical, probably should not use the same method.

Bayesian methods are good at helping *me* understand my beliefs and change them as new information comes in.  That *me* could be an *us* and the *my* could be an *our*.  If you have no beliefs on the topic, why do you even need to consider the topic?

Frequentist and Maximum Likelihood methods work really well when we lack prior belief because they minimize the maximum amount of risk that you will be facing.  Indeed, any two people that get the same result on a t-test with the same cutoff criterion should infer the same thing and decide the same thing.  That should not be true with Bayesian methods.

Now let us get back to my area of expertise.  How should *I* gamble money?

Well, it turns out that there are two very nice binding sets of rules that govern my behavior when money is involved.  The first is the Dutch Book Theorem.  If I were to massively oversimplify it, it says that if you gamble, you can never use a non-Bayesian method or it is possible to force you to take a sure loss.  In some cases, I can force you to take a sure loss 100% of the time.

If you are in finance, as I am, methods such as ordinary least squares can guarantee a loss to the user.  I do some interesting training exercises to show how that is done.  You get some seriously stunned looks when they lose and realized they could never have won.  Simple rule, you cannot use non-Bayesian methods when placing money at risk in a gambling or market type of situation.

The second rule comes because the Dutch Book Theorem and its converse imply that it is necessary to use a Bayesian method but it doesn't say that it is sufficient.  It turns out that it is not a sufficient criterion.

The second rule requires the use of a proper prior built from actual information.  The reason is that all admissible Frequentist rules are either the limiting form of a Bayesian rule or match the Bayesian outcome in every sample.  That leads to the question of whether or not the Frequentist solution inherits the Bayesian blessing when gambling, or if there are limits on Bayesian gambling.

The result is that there are limits on Bayesian gambling.  A market maker or bookie that is clueless about the game they are playing can be forced to take losses by an informed actor.  Unfortunately, I don't have citations where I am at. I print things out and put them in binders and I am not near my binders.  Nonetheless, if you did an academic search on the Dutch Book Theorem, you would likely come across them pretty quickly.

Your question is about the obvious problem of "what if the prior is wrong?"  Well, it can never be wrong because, for it to be valid, it should reflect your beliefs.  It isn't that the prior is wrong, it is that your beliefs are wrong.  The data should update your beliefs.  If you are very prejudiced, then they may be updated by an almost imperceptibly small amount.

Remember, in the Frequentist world, $\theta$ is a fixed point.  There is a correct single answer.  In the Bayesian world, $\theta$ is a random variable.  Even if there is a fixed, correct answer, it is quite likely that you will never find it.  That is okay, you have your distribution and if it is in the near neighborhood of reality, then all is well.

*You cannot pass COVID on to others because COVID does not exist, therefore you do not need to isolate or quarantine if somebody tells you that you are exposed.*

That is a belief.  It is wrong, but it is a belief.  Given the right type of data, you may interfere with or alter that belief.  Bayesian methods begin with you and where you are at.

How do you know that your sample of French people was representative?  Could you not have acquired a pleasant and welcoming subsample by chance?  Why trust the data *alone*?  Why not, instead, question if you are prejudiced?

Comment: "If you gamble, you can never use a non-Bayesian method or it is possible to force you to take a sure loss" - this is not quite true. (a) There may be no real opponent enforcing the sure loss (even the setup of the real situation may not allow anyone to do so).

Comment: (b) There's a real football betting experiment described in P. Walley's "Statistical Reasoning with Imprecise Probabilities" in which the consistent Bayesian had about the worst results of all. People using imprecise probabilities have the option to refuse certain bets (only bet when a bet looks favourable to them), whereas the Bayesian will bet all the time. In real life you don't normally have to bet all the time, so the imprecise probability approach (where you refuse bets that don't look safe enough to you) looks better (and is better in that experiment).

Comment: @Lewian it may be true that there is no real opponent to enforce the sure loss.  The Dutch Book Theorem only guarantees that if one exists, then they cannot put you in that position.  You are correct.  The fact that losses can exist does not imply that anybody noticed them.  I will have to look at Walley's article.  I will have to understand why the Bayesian must bet all the time as I agree with you.  Only bookies, banks, insurers and market makers can be in the position of forced or nearly forced bets. It is why underwriting exists.

Comment: Obviously in reality a Bayesian can refuse bets; however the Dutch Book argument relies on the opponent being able to enforce certain bets if you offer certain other bets, so it is only valid if you can be forced to bet.

Comment: Thanks, I will reflect on your answer but on the question "Why trust the data alone?" because if the data come from a random sample, then it is your best bet to estimate the true parameter. Again, I am a social scientist, the research questions are very different from betting and money investments.

Comment: I still dont get why you can be a Frequentist and still have priors. For instance, if you know that your sample over-represent men, then you can correct this. You start with the data and correct, like in post-stratification.

Comment: @Lewian that is true.  It assumes the bookie must accept all bets at stated prices.  I will look at that piece.

Comment: @giac the over-representation of men is in the sample space and not the parameter space.  That type of correction is different in kind from the use of a prior.  The prior and the likelihood do not care that you oversampled men, however, if you believe that sex matters, then treating both sexes as different would matter.

Comment: @giac This paper... https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/rssa.12276 ... has something on "falsificationist Bayes", i.e., using Bayesian statistics with a frequentist interpretation of probability (Sec 5, 5.5 in particular).

Comment: @giac, most investers and gamblers would agree that long-run probabilities are the best bet compared to subjective beliefs.  I think this is the underlying point of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

From whatever little I know about Bayesian method, the best use case is when you have limited pieces of evidence which by themselves are not enough to make a frequentist probability with reliability. But the little evidence you have can add to an informative prior probability to take you closer to the truth.

In the particular example you provided, I don't see a great use case for Bayesian application, but consider how you can solve this problem without using Bayesian interpretation - question from [arbital](https://arbital.com/p/bayes_rule/?l=693)

> Suppose there's a bathtub full of coins:
> Half the coins are "fair" and have a 50% probability of coming up Heads each time they are thrown.
> A third of the coins are biased to produce Heads 25% of the time (Tails 75%).
> The remaining sixth of the coins are biased to produce Heads 75% of the time.
> You randomly draw a coin, flip it three times, and get the result HTH. What's the chance this is a fair coin?

Would it be doable if you throw away the prior information and see how you can answer the question maybe rephrased as "what is the probability of heads for a single toss of this coin which gave a HTH"?

Answer (score -2):

A prior is useful for incorporating historical information, analogous to a fixed effect meta-analysis.  Because Bayesians define parameters as random variables and probability as the belief of the experimenter they may feel much freer to incorporate information from other studies or their personal beliefs.  In contrast, because frequentists are concerned with the performance of their testing procedure they may scrutinize the compatibility of studies.  The frequentist needs to feel comfortable assuming the unknown fixed true quantity being investigated in each study is identical (even if the subject-level observations are not necessarily exchangeable).  This may be a big assumption to make, analgous to assuming an informative Bayesian prior.  Using a purely subjective Bayesian prior is analogous to performing a meta-analysis with hypothetical experimental data.

I will argue against using a Bayesian prior and in favor of a frequentist meta-analysis, beginning with an example taken from *Decision Making in Drug Development via Confidence Distributions* [(Johnson 2021)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350055507_Decision_Making_in_Drug_Development_via_Confidence_Distributions).  The primary reason not to use a Bayesian prior is that a subjective interpretation of probability as a measure of belief is unfalsifiable [(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/bayesian-vs-frequentist-interpretations-of-probability/503079#503079)[(2)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539351/307000).

A *confidence distribution* $H(\theta,\boldsymbol{x})$ as a function of the hypothesis and observed data has the appearance of a cdf on the parameter space and depicts p-values and confidence intervals of all levels based on a particular testing procedure.  This same information can be displayed as a confidence density and a confidence curve.

The figure below depicts a meta-analysis using confidence distributions for a binomial proportion $\theta$. Density (a) represents an informative prior distribution based on historical data and a vague conjugate prior with an estimate of 0.90 and a sample size of n = 50. This same information is depicted in (b) as a confidence density resulting from a likelihood ratio test. A similar confidence density can be produced by inverting a Wald test with a logit link. The posterior based on the current data binomial likelihood and a vague conjugate prior is shown in (c) with an estimate of 0.87 resulting from n = 30. This same information can be represented as a likelihood ratio confidence density, (d). Using Bayes theorem, (a) and (c) combine to form (e). Multipliying the historical and current likelihoods and inverting a likelihood ratio test forms (f). This multiplication of independent likelihoods is precisely what Bayes theorem accomplishes (plus normalization), without the inversion of a hypothesis test.

[image]

The confidence densities above can be interpreted under a Neyman-Pearson framework using a pre-specified null hypothesis and type I error rate.  they can also be interpreted under a Fisherian framework of evidential p-values to compare the plausibility of multiple hypotheses, not necessarily pre-specified.  Many Bayesians will use a Dutch book argument in support of posterior probability.  Here is an example where the long-run characteristics of a likelihood ratio test are used to form a Dutch book against two different Bayesian posteriors. [(3)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/506653/307000)

Comment: I don't really get this criticism that Bayesian methods are "unfalsifiable". The classic frequentist approach is to calculate a p-value and then somehow use that p-value to make a decision, such as whether to proceed to mass manufacture of a vaccine. The frequentist may base this decision on whether the p-value is below some arbitrary threshold such as 0.05. What is falsifiable about the choice of 0.05 here? Of course, you could simply never make any decisions based on your p-values, but that raises the question of why you are even doing statistics in the first place.

Comment: Bayesian methods are unfalsifiable as long as Bayesian probabilities are taken to model belief rather than the data generating process in reality, although a Bayesian belief can turn out to be badly calibrated to reality and Bayesians can check that. However, Bayesian statistics can also be applied in a falsifiable way, see Andrew Gelman's work and in particular Sec. 5.5 here (as linked in another comment already): https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/rssa.12276

Comment: @Geoffrey, thanks for sending the paper I will have a look at it

Comment: Only if there exists a real-life mechanism by which we can sample values of $\theta$ can a probability distribution for $\theta$ be verified.  In such settings probability statements about $\theta$ will have a purely frequentist interpretation.  The challenge then is to apply the posterior probabilitly statements to the $\theta$ under investigation in a [meaningful way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/539352/307000).

Comment: @fblundun I suggest you look up what it means for something to be falsifiable.  An error rate is set by design.  Someone else could try to falsify this error rate by claming the pre-specified error rate is something different, but one would simply verify the error rate specified in the analysis plan.  In a similar fashion a Bayesian can pre-specify a prior by design, and in that sense it is unfalsifiable, but posterior belief is not a verifiable statement about the actual parameter, the hypothesis, nor the experiment.  In that sense Bayesian belief is unfalsifiable.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson so is the belief "the p-value threshold for mass manufacturing the vaccine should be 0.05 rather than 0.04 or 0.06" falsifiable? If not, that would suggest that there is no way to make use of p-values without an unfalsifiable interpretation step.

Comment: Arbitrary and unfalsifiable are not the same.  If I specify an acceptable type I error rate, however arbitrary, that is verifiable.  If I calculate a p-value under a null hypothesis, that is a verifiable statement about the experiment as a function of the hypothesis.  If we instead argue about our beliefs we can never be proven wrong.  The only verification we can do is to ask the experimenter if he in fact feels according to the posterior.  We are no longer investigating the truth, we are investigating his beliefs.  Probability can either measure the experimenter or the experiment.

Comment: Here is a link to a related [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539351/307000).

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson But you also can't verify that 0.05 is the right p-value threshold to use for the decision. Once you admit that decisions based on p-value thresholds are arbitrary, how is that any better than using an unfalsifiable Bayesian prior? Both methods involve relying on the experimenter's personal opinions to make a decision. Even if we are both frequentists, we still end up arguing over our beliefs about whether the p-value is low enough to mass produce the vaccine!

Comment: I agree that 0.05 is arbitrary.  I much prefer a Fisherian framekwork using evidential p-values.  This allows us to explore the plausibility of several hypotheses given the data.  A p-value of 0.06 or 0.07 or 0.10 does not result in an immediate acceptance of the null hypothesis using an arbitrary 0.05 error threshold.   Ultimately it comes down to a decision made by a human who is balancing different errors.  Is it worse to withold a vaccine that works or to mass produce a dud?  Depending on the answer one might use a higher significante level to avoid a Type II error.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/506653/307000) where it is not immediately obvious what the evidence is provided by the data using an objective Bayesian approach.  The frequentist analog to this would be choosing between different hypothesis tests to use.  What it really boils down to is [interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539351/307000).

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson right - I don't understand why "a decision made by a human who is balancing different errors" is any more objective than "a decision made using a subjective prior". You mentioned deciding to change the significance level to reduce the Type II error rate, but there is no way to assess the risk of a Type II error without introducing something like a prior.

Comment: If you can provide a solution to the question posed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539351/307000) then you will have your answer.  Here is a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350055507_Decision_Making_in_Drug_Development_via_Confidence_Distributions) on power and probability of success, the flipside of type II error.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson the power of a test depends on the true value of the parameter. To assess the power of the vaccination trials you would need something like a prior probability distribution on how effective the vaccine is - if you think that the vaccine is likely to only provide some protection, you will be more worried about Type II errors than if you think the vaccine is likely to provide strong protection. The question you linked isn't really relevant - you complained about Bayesian unfalsifiability, so it's on you to say why that's worse than subjective choice of significance level.

Comment: A frequentist significance level is just as arbitrary as a Bayesian significance level (posterior probability) for decision making.  Neither are unfalsifiable, just arbitrary.  What is unfalsifiable is a subjective interpretation of probability.  I suggest you read the answer I provided in the question I linked to, as well as the paper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128413/discussion-between-fblundun-and-geoffrey-johnson).