# Bayesian estimation difference between inferences is conjugate prior and non informative prior

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior, bayesian-optimization

What are the differences in the inferences using non-informative (specifically Jeffrys) priors as compared to the conjugate prior?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is as between any other two priors: Bayes theorem is

$$
p(\theta|X) \propto p(X|\theta)\; p(\theta)
$$

so whatever you multiply the likelihood with, it will have some impact on the posterior. The idea of ["uniformative" priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392373/understanding-definition-of-informative-and-uninformative-prior-distribution) is that they have as little impact on the posterior as possible, though [it is not true that they convey "no" information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information). Conjugate priors are just priors that can be used with some distributions, so that posterior has a closed-form solution.

Moreover, you can have conjugate priors that are "uninformative", for example for binomial likelihood, beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=\beta=1$ (uniform), or $\alpha=\beta=1/2$ (Jeffreys prior).